# Very basic function with parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, user-input

I'm very new to Python and an absolute beginner in functions. I tried to search for the answer but I haven't found it, although I'm sure it's trivial. I want to define a function with a parameter as input. Then I want to call the function, where the user can define the parameter, and run it.

Basically I want to get a palindrome with user input. So that if the function is called, e.g. palindrome(d), we get a print of abcdcba.

I already have the function working with a raw_input line from the user. But I want the user to call the function as palindrome(letter), so palindrome(g) for example.

```
def palindrome():
    input = raw_input("Till what letter would you like to have the palindrome: ")
    n = ord(input)
    for i in range(n - 97):
    print(chr(97 + i)),
    for j in range(n - 96):
        print(chr(n - j)),

palindrome()
```

I tried

```
def palindrome('a'):
    n = ord(a)
    for i in range(n - 97):
        print(chr(97 + i)),
    for j in range(n - 96):
        print(chr(n - j)),

 palindrome(c)
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: You have the quotes in the wrong place. The function should be _declared_ `def palindrome(a):`, and should be _called_ with `palindrome('c')`

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the answer I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Is it also possible to rewrite it so that palindrome(k) would work in stead of only palindrome('k') ?

Comment: No, that isn't possible. Unquoted `k` means the variable named `k`, not the character `'k'`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the quotes in the wrong place.

The function should be **declared** as

```
def palindrome(a):
```

because `a` is a name for the variable that will be used within the function, not the character `'a'`.

And the function should be **called** with

```
palindrome('c')
```

Quoted text indicates a string literal: it is the content of the characters within the quotes rather than an identifier for a variable.